# Get directory name from full directory path regardless of trailing slash

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get the directory name from its path regardless of any of having a trailing backslash. For example, user may input one of the following 2 strings and I need the name of logs directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Logs"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Logs\"
```

None of the following gives correct answer (`"Logs"`):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(m_logsDir);
FileInfo(m_logsDir).Directory.Name;
```

They apparently analyze the path string and in the 1st example decide that `Logs` is a file while it's really a directory.

So it should check if the last word (`Logs` in our case) is really a directory; if yes, return it, if no (Logs might be a file too), return a parent directory. If would require dealing with the actual filesystem rather than analyzing the string itself.

Is there any standard function to do that?

Comment: A file does not need to have an extension

Comment: Can you clarify your question, do you want to ensure your grabbing the name of the Log Folder or do you simply want the Logs directory?

Comment: I want to get "Logs" but be sure that it's really the folder and not a file.
Checking for `System.IO.Directory.Exists(m_logsDir)` looks to be a feasible solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new DirectoryInfo(m_logsDir).Name;
```

Comment: That works for my 2 examples, but what happens if Logs is really a file rather than a directory? Will it throw an exception?

Comment: No but DirectoryInfo has an Exists Property that you can simply check.

Comment: If "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Logs" is a File, `new DirectoryInfo(m_logsDir).Exists` returns false. You will have an IOException if you try to create the directory (`new DirectoryInfo(m_logsDir).Create();`)

Answer (score 3):

This may help

```
var result = System.IO.Directory.Exists(m_logsDir) ? 
              m_logsDir: 
              System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(m_logsDir);
```

Comment: It feels less efficient than the answer I posted where you simply check the flag

Comment: @dimnnv
In the question you said that the correct answer is "Logs". The accepted answer doesn't return that

Answer (score 1):

For this we have a snippet of code along the lines of:

```
m_logsDir.HasFlag(FileAttribute.Directory); //.NET 4.0
```

or

```
(File.GetAttributes(m_logsDir) & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory; // Before .NET 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase my answer, because you have two potential flaws by the distinguishing factors.  If you do:

```
var additional = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Logs\";
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(additional);
```

Your output would be as intended, `Logs`.  However, if you do:

```
var additional = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Logs";
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(additional);
```

Your output would be `My Program`, which causes a difference in output.  I would either try to enforce the ending `\` otherwise you may be able to do something such as this:

```
var additional = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Logs";
var filter = additional.Split('\\');
var getLast = filter.Last(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: If there wasn't a \ at the end this would return "My Program".

Comment: @Ralf Yes, that is why I revised my answer.

Comment: Better but ... Path doesn't know nothing about the filesystem its just about syntax. And dimnv wants to differantiate between file and directory so DirectoryInfo is the better option compared to the Path class.

Comment: @Ralf Well, you could add a *and* and make sure it doesn't contain a `.`.  However, it may open another can of worms, so it may not be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the previous answer, you could enforce the trailing slash like this:

`Path.GetDirectoryName(m_logsDir + "\");`

Ugly but it seems to work - whether there's 0 or 1 slash at the end.  The double-slash is treated like a single-slash by GetDirectoryName.